# Modelo conceitual de dois relacionamentos entre duas entidades

Tags: modelo-relacional

Olá, estou começando o estudo sobre modelagem conceitual e entidade relacionamento até que me deparei com uma dúvida e até agora não encontrei exemplos semelhantes.

Para simplificar, tenho duas entidades, TIME e PARTIDA. Para cada instância de PARTIDA, preciso ter duas instâncias de TIME relacionados com ela.

Com isso em mente montei o diagrama dessa imagem, que me gerou a dúvida, pois não vi nenhum exemplo parecido, então queria saber se é assim mesmo ou tem outra forma de resolver esse cenário?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gostei do estudo de caso, mas acho que ainda precisa de mais atributos para as entidades. Por exemplo, o que faz uma partida única, além dos times que participam, são o horário, data, pontuação/gols, lugar onde está acontecendo, etc. Sim, você está indo pelo caminho certo. Ainda acho que você deve formular uma pergunta mais clara: qual sua dúvida *especificamente*?

Comment: Não cheguei colocar todos os atributos, mas eles existem sim como os que você sugeriu. Só tentei focar no caso de existir dois relacionamentos entre duas classes, afinal a maior parte dos exemplos tem um relacionamento entre duas classes, ou tem uma entidade associativa nos relacionamentos n:m.

Minha dúvida é: Do ponto de vista do modelo conceitual, esses dois relacionamentos entre duas classes é válido?

Comment: Me parece que não, mas é o que eu sempre digo, depende dos requisitos que não sabemos. O que manda é sempre o requisito, é o caso concreto, não é um regra boba criada por alguém do que é certo ou errado.

Comment: Concordo em parte com o @Maniero. Como as regras têm atributos entre elas, as relações, em teria, deveriam se referir aos atributos e não, como classicamente nos referimos, às entidades em si. Por outro lado, falta completude quando se trata dos requisitos do modelo. Recomendo uma leitura do seguinte artigo: http://academic2.strose.edu/math_and_science/avitabij/cis503fall06/answers3.htm

Comment: Obrigado, o artigo tem o exato exemplo que eu precisava para tirar a dúvida, que era somente se pode haver mais de um relacionamento entre duas entidades.

Falha minha ter abstraído maior parte das informações do problema e muitos ficarem na dúvida de qual realmente era minha questão, mas foi resolvido!

Answer (score 1):

Amigo então, não tenho diagramador no meu pc pois formatei então fiz no paint mesmo. O negócio é que você não precisa ter dois jogos você pode colocar tipo direto na tabela partida. Porém o certo mesmo é criar uma tabela própria para tipo de jogo e ligar com a partida.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta não está de acordo com as convenções de diagramas Entida-relacionamento (DER). Considere seguir alguma notação, como UML e corrija sua resposta: https://www.devmedia.com.br/modelo-entidade-relacionamento-mer-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento-der/14332

Answer (score 0):

Ola meu nobre amigo tudo bem?  Suponho que nosso amigo quis lhe passar este diagrama. Vemos que a entidade "tipo partida" é fraca em relação a partida, assim sendo possui seu id código. boa sorte!!

[image: Diagrama Partida]